# Does cost of EC2 on AWS increase at the same rate as user count?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm getting ready to launch a mobile app that I have hosted on AWS with an EC2 instance. ($0.0464 per On Demand Linux t2.medium Instance Hour).

This past month I was charged $112 for the EC2 usage, but only had a handful of internal users testing the private version of the app. It's a fairly simple app, not anything that should require a lot of computing power.

So what I'm wondering is if 10 users and dev team costs $112/mo, what happens if I get 1,000 users, or 10k users? Would the cost increase 100x, 1000x? I can't imagine getting auto-billed for $112,000 for a month of service with a small user base like 10k users.

Thanks for any help and guidance, I don't know much about AWS.

Here are the details of my billing for last month:
[image: Billing details]

Comment: What exactly are you scaling on? You will need to provide more details of your setup :)

Comment: Amazon doesn't know how many users your EC2 instance has. You are just charged for the cost of the EC2 instance. It sounds like you have much more than one t2.medium instance in your account if you are getting charged that much.

Comment: "EC2 Usage" has a lot of components. You should use Cost Explorer to find out where you're actually spending money.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full EC2 "Bill Details" from your Billing Dashboard. (Click "Bill Details" in the top-right and expand the EC2 section.)

Comment: @MarkB  thank you for your reply. I've edited the description with a link to a screenshot of my billing details: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPnyh.png  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you, here are the billing details: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPnyh.png

Comment: @Parsifal when i go to Cost Explorer it shows that all my cost is coming from 
Usage Type: USE2-BoxUsage:t2.medium
API Operation: RunInstances

Comment: @MarkB I do have 3 EC2 instances, but only 1 is currently in use. The other two are for a project that is dormant and are not using any resources. I saw the breakdown somewhere when I was looking around yesterday but can't find it now.

Comment: If the EC2 instances are running, you are getting charged for them. It is using Amazon's resources as long as it is running, so you will be charged accordingly. Amazon doesn't care if you are actually using it or not, they only care that you have a server running, using their hardware.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you so much!! That's a huge relief. I'll turn off those others. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The billing page shows 2219 hours of `t2.medium` during this billing month.

That is the equivalent of 92 days. So, it might be 3 instances running for a full month.

Amazon EC2 is charged when the instance is in the **Running** state. If you are not using an instance, you can **Stop** the instance. The attached disks (EBS) will still be charged, but there will be no charge for the instance itself.

The charge is not based on the number of users, nor how 'busy' the instance is. It is simply charged when the instance is 'running'. This is because computer resources are exclusively assigned to instances (CPU, RAM) that nobody else can use.

**Bottom line:** Stop instances that you don't need. Use the smallest instance type for your use-case to reduce costs.

If you were not aware of the charges involved, you can contact AWS Customer Service and request a refund.

FYI, the T2 and T3 family are great for workloads that occasionally 'burst' but then have low-usage periods, but they are not great for sustained workloads. See: [Burstable performance instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm laughing right now at how ridiculously simple the answer was, and how little I understand these things. I really appreciate you taking the time to provide such a thorough answer.